# Need fix for EsLint error: Gratuitous parentheses around expression-no-extra-parens

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sonarqube, eslint

i'm getting error when i'm running ESLint on my JavaScript code.

```
var crslWt = 100;
var totCrslWt = (crslWt/2)-20;
```

i'm getting error

> Gratuitous parentheses around expression  no-extra-parens

Comment: Then remove the parentheses to conform to the rule?

Comment: It's not like the code contains an abundance of parentheses. It isn't hard to figure out which pair it is referring to.

Comment: If i remove the parens in which order operator precedence works?

Comment: @crazyarun — Have you tried [looking it up](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+operator+precedence&oq=javascript+operator+pre&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3795j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or trusting that the linter is correct when it says the parentheses are gratuitous?

Comment: First division, then subtraction. ESLint is aware of that, hence why you get the error. If the code was `crslWt/(2-20);` then removing the brackets changes the meaning and ESLint would not issue a rule violation.

Comment: Here `(crslWt / 2) - 20;` i just gave precedence for calculation order.

Comment: `(crslWt / 2) - 20` and `crslWt / 2 - 20` are identical in terms of execution and outcome. Which is why the parentheses are redundant and thus you get the rule violation from ESLint.

Comment: oh...thanks man.. @vlaz

Comment: @vlaz parentheses are added to gain readability and is very common to see this formatting in any programming language (even school math exercises, although the rules in math are the same)

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I know that but if the rule is enabled, then the code style forbids doing that. Therefore, to conform to the style guide, the parantheses should be removed. This, in turn, would not change the meaning of the expression. I don't know why you chose to clarify something that wasn't in question here.

Comment: @vlaz the question states "Need fix eslint error.." so you can fix either linter or code. Bacause code need to be much readable as possible I would prefer to fix the linter, thats it.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio:

[image]

Change the following line:

```
"no-extra-parens": 1,
```

to

```
"no-extra-parens": 0,
```

Comment: Simply removing the parenthesis will fix the issue, but sometimes you want parenthesis for clarity.  For example a || (b && c) will cause the warning, but a || b && c just doesn't look as clear to some people (including myself).  Yes the parens are extra, but adding them clarifies the statement to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to enforce option  `{ "nestedBinaryExpressions": false }`.

**From [official documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-parens#nestedbinaryexpressions):**

> Examples of **correct** code for this rule with the "all" and {
>   "nestedBinaryExpressions": false } options:

```
/* eslint no-extra-parens: ["error", "all", { "nestedBinaryExpressions": false }] */

x = a || (b && c);
x = a + (b * c);
x = (a * b) / c;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply remove parentheses around `crslWt/2`.

`/` operator [takes precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) over `-`, therefore parentheses in this case are technically redundant

Comment: Sometimes it's not immediately clear and extra parentheses are helpful to speed reading.